# Loop in bash script isnt capturing all lines in an file

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

My current code is going through a .csv file and then queries a database to obtain information derived from roles and tasks. However, this portion of the script is only reading the first line of the .csv file. Any recommendations on how to read multiple lines of the .csv?

```
#!/bin/bash
> sql_stmnts.txt
> bad_info.txt

INPUT_FILE='test.csv'

IFS=','

while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7; do

   #echo "f1='$f1', f2='$f2', f3='$f3', f4='$f4', f5='$f5', f6='$f6', f7='$f7'"

   user_id=$(echo "${f1//\"/}")
   first_name=$(echo "${f2//\"/}")
   last_name=$(echo "${f3//\"/}")
   title=$(echo "${f4//\"/}")
   requestor=$(echo "${f5//\"/}")
   request_email=$(echo "${f6//\"/}")
   roles=$(echo "$f7"| sed 's/"\(.[^"]*\)".*/\1/')
   tasks=$(echo "$f7"| sed 's/".[^"]*".*"\(.[^"]*\)"/\1/')

   roles=${roles//, /,}
   tasks=${tasks//, /,}

   for i in $roles
   do
       if sql_string=$(sshpass -p XXXXXX ssh jlefler@11.11.11.11 'mysql --skip-column-names -u root -pxxxxxx database -e "select id from roles where binary role_name='"'${i}';"'"'); then
          if [[ -n $sql_string ]]; then
             echo  "insert into user_roles (USER_ID, ROLE_ID, version) select id, $sql_string, 1 from users where user_id in ('$user_id');" >> sql_stmnts.txt
          else
             echo "$user_id - $i is a bad role" >> bad_info.txt
       fi
       else
          echo "Query Didn't Execute"
       fi
   done

   for i in $tasks
   do
       if sql_string=$(sshpass -p XXXXXXX ssh jlefler@11.11.11.11 'mysql --skip-column-names -u root -xxxxxxx database -e "select id from groups where binary group_name='"'${i}';"'"'); then
          if [[ -n $sql_string ]]; then
             echo  "insert into membership (USER_ID, group_ID, version) select id, $sql_string, 1 from users where user_id in ('$user_id');" >> sql_stmnts.txt
          else
             echo "$user_id - $i is a bad task" >> bad_info.txt
       fi
       else
          echo "Query Didn't Execute"
       fi
   done

done < $INPUT_FILE
```

When running with bash -x option, this is output at the end of the first line:

```
+ sql_string=3
+ [[ -n 3 ]]
+ echo 'insert into membership (USER_ID, group_ID, version) select id, 3, 1 from users where user_id in ('\''jlefler'\'');'
+ read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
```

Comment: that wud work if you are putting lines in a file. then done < file.txt will make variable "line" to get the whole line. This assumes you have only fixed # of fields in a line.

Comment: The problem is this code only reads the first line of the .csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop. I'm just setting sql_string to a random#. The example just shows you can use for loop to achieve the same.

**For ex:**
[c1@server CLI]$ cat 1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create fresh .txt files. You don't have to use the next 2 lines if you want them to be appended each time you run your script.
>a.txt
>b.txt

arr=("Case Manager" "Case Collector" "Engineer")
for line in "${arr[@]}"; do
      ##I'm just setting sql_string to a value. Set accordingly per your use.  
      if sql_string=$RANDOM ; then
         if [[ -n $sql_string ]]; then
            echo  $line - "$sql_string" >> a.txt
         else
            echo "No Data Found" >> b.txt
      fi
      else
         echo "Query Didn't Execute"
      fi
done
```

[c1@server CLI]$ cat a.txt

```
Case Manager - 13101
Case Collector - 3325
Engineer - 30248
```

[c1@server CLI]$

Comment: This does not work. It directs all the output to b.txt Something about the sql_string command is only reading the first element in the array - for the life of me I have no idea what it is.

Comment: It works, are you using Bash? In my case, b.txt is 0 bytes. a.txt has some data. Don't use RANDOM (as i used it for ex purpose). Just change the while loop line and replace it with for loop like I stated above and see if it'll work. Also, you just need done (instead of done <<< "$arr"). Also for debugging purpose, try running the script as "bash -x script.sh" if you are using bash or use similar debug option. The reason your b.txt is populating can be due to sql_string variable being NULL.

Comment: copy paste the script in a Linux session and see what you are getting in file a.txt and b.txt. Again, if you dont see the expected output, run the script with "bash -x 1.sh" and see why it's going in else condition (what's inside sql_string).

Comment: I managed to get it to work, but it only reads the first line of my file. It quits after reading the first line of test.csv. I will update my description.

Comment: did you copy /paste the script i answered above and saw what's in a.txt and b.txt? Also run with : bash -x 1.sh (and analyze the output)

Comment: Are you using a file (which contains those values or are you using an array ??) If you are using a file, then you can still use while loop and end the loop with : done < yourFileWhichHasLines.txt

Comment: I've updated my original post with the new code and the results of the 'bash -x' process execution.